# Non Manifold object ? why hole is not print with 3D Printer?

Tags: normals, 3d-printing

I don't undestand when why i print my gear (with central hole) the hole (only on the top) is fill and not print.

There's problem in my blend project ?
Is non manifold ?

I hope someone can help me !

Sorry for my english...

[image]

Comment: you need to recalculate the normals (in Edit mode, select all and ctrl N), maybe it causes problems? I don't know enough about 3D print...

Comment: You are great ! works !!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some normals are flipped, so go in *Edit* mode, select all and recalculate the normals with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> (shortcut since 2.8)